# How can I duplicate a gameObject in code Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I want to duplicate the gameObject called "Damaged".

[image]

I want it to have the exact name, position and to be a child under the gameObject Boss. The whole idea is that every time I call a function, a gameObject should be created, that has an Animator with a single animation, then when the animation is played, there is an event which destroys that gameObject. I tried the obvious Instance solution and I get the object outside the parent class.:

[image]

```cs
GameObject duplicate = Instantiate(damageText, transform.position, transform.rotation);
animator.SetTrigger("Damage");
```

Overall, I need help to move the newly created gameObject as a child under the Boss object and trigger the animation for that gameObject. I tried searching it up, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: `Instantiate` has an overload taking the desired `parent` transform ... -> `GameObject duplicate = Instantiate(damageText, transform.position, transform.rotation, yourParentransform);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the parent directly after creation and run the animator's Trigger.

```cs
GameObject duplicate = Instantiate(damageText, transform.position, transform.rotation, transform.parent);
animator.SetTrigger("Damage");

duplicate.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Damage");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your Instanciate to add parent transform it should work, instanciate can take parent transform as parameter just add it after like this :

```
GameObject duplicate = Instantiate(damageText, transform.position, transform.rotation, "parent transform here");
animator.SetTrigger("Damage");
```

If you want to get parent transform you can either find it with its name Like so : `Transform bossTransform = GameObject.Find("name").tranform;` or you can add it as a public component to your script : `public Transform bossTransform;`